# How to import i18n with vue 3 + vite?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vite, vue-i18n

In my vite + vue 3 project, I import i18n like this

```
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
```

But I then get this error in the dev tools console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/vue-i18n.js?v=3de9cdf7' does not provide an export named 'default' (at i18n.ts:1:8)
```

How can I resovle this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it needed this

```
import * as VueI18n from "vue-i18n";
```